# Convert a byte array into an image w/o FromStream (for Mono)

Tags: c#, .net, image, mono, system.drawing

I am trying to find a way, in C#, to convert a byte array to an `Image` without using `Image.FromStream`.

I would like a conversion routine that can be used in Windows as well as Linux, and I am using Mono to interpret the code. Analyzing the code (with the `Image.FromStream`) using MonoTools 2.0 reports that `FromStream` is not supported.

Is there a more manual, so-to-speak, way of getting the data into the `Image` object? I imagine I need to use `FromHbitmap` somehow by creating a handle to the byte array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image.FromStream` is supported ([and has been supported for a long time](https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Image.cs)) in Mono and works without any problems. If MoMA is reporting problems - are you sure you are using a current definition file (they hadn't been updated for the latest release, but a plain 2.10 should also show you "supported").

Comment: That is good news. I am using Mono 2.10 and MoMA looks like it is 2.8. Thank you for your help.